# Matplotlib animation slows down when adding patches

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I wanted to visualize the path of a 2D-algorithm. So I wrote a short Python code, that produces such a animation. The problem is, that for each pixel (a `plt.Rectangle`) I add, the code gets slower and slower. The first 20 pixels get displayed in about 1 second, the last 20 pixels take already 3 seconds. And obviously it gets even worse for bigger grids and more pixels.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 7)
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 20), ylim=(0, 20))

pixels = list()

def init():
    return list()

def animate(i):
    index = len(pixels)
    index_x, index_y = index // 20, index % 20

    pixel = plt.Rectangle((index_x, index_y), 1, 1, fc='r')
    ax.add_patch(pixel)
    pixels.append(pixel)
    return pixels

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                               init_func=init, 
                               frames=100, 
                               interval=5,
                               blit=True)

plt.show()
```

It's quite clear to me, why it takes longer. Since the number of patches gets bigger and bigger each frame, matplotlibs rendering gets slower and slower. But not this slow! How can I get more speed? Is there a way that I can keep the old plot and only overwrite the current pixel?

Answer (score 1):

I tried timing the animate function and for some reason there is no apparent slowdown in the function itself. Besides, `blit` should ensure only the latest rectangle is drawn. A possible way to prevent the redraw you suggest is to rasterize the plot with,

```
    m=ax.add_patch(pixel)
    m.set_rasterized(True)
```

Although this doesn't seem to improve speed for my timing. I think the increase must result somewhere in matplotlib when updating the plot. This is clear using interactive plotting, e.g.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 7)
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 20), ylim=(0, 20))
npx = 20; npy = 20
Npix = npx*npy
plt.ion()
plt.show()
for i in range(Npix):
    #ax.cla()
    t0 = time.time()
    index_x, index_y = i // 20, i % 20

    pixel = plt.Rectangle((index_x, index_y), 1, 1, fc='r')
    ax.add_patch(pixel)

    fig.set_rasterized(True)
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    t1 = time.time()
    print("Time=",i,t1-t0)
```

Which gives for the rasterised, non-rasterised and cleared axis (`ax.cla`) case,

[image: Time for each plot <code>t1-t0</code> per rectangle on <code>y</code> vs rectangle number on <code>x</code>]

I'm not sure why this happens, maybe someone with better insight into matplotlib would be able to help. One way to speed up the plot is to setup and put all rectangles in a `patchcollection`. Then the animation just changes the facecolor so only the rectangles which need be shown are displayed,

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 7)
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 20), ylim=(0, 20))
npx = 20; npy = 20
Npix = npx*npy
displayed = np.zeros((npx, npy, 4))
pixels = []

def init():
    for index in range(Npix):
        index_x, index_y = index // npx, index % npy

        pixel = plt.Rectangle((index_x, index_y), 1, 1, fc='r', ec='none')
        pixels.append(pixel)

    return pixels

pixels = init()
collection = PatchCollection(pixels, match_original=True, animated=True)
ax.add_collection(collection)

def animate(index):
    index_x, index_y = index // npx, index % npy
    displayed[index_x, index_y] = [1, 0, 0, 1]
    collection.set_facecolors(displayed.reshape(-1, 4))
    return (collection,)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                               frames=400,
                               interval=1, 
                               blit=True, 
                               repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

This is much faster, although I couldn't work out how to turn edges on or off so just disable for all rectangles.