# Decreasing animation speed in matplotlib using patches

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

The following codes works correctly, but during animation time the process becomes slower and slower. I feel it has something to do with the fact that more and more patches accumulate. But I am not really an expert concerning animations with matplotlib and do not have a clue to keep the speed constant for longer sequences. 
Before someone asks: My problems seem similar to this question ["Matplotlib animation slows down when adding patches"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053759/matplotlib-animation-slows-down-when-adding-patches), but the suggested solution -- which is not finaly anyway -- does not work out in my case. Among other problems I really need a kind of class design like the one in the example code.

Thanks for any suggestions

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

class myMovie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))
        self.toDraw = []
        for i in range(10):
            agent = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.75, fc=(i/10,0,0))
            self.toDraw.append(agent)

    def init(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.toDraw[i].center = (50,50)
            self.ax.add_patch(self.toDraw[i])
        return []

    def animationManage(self,i):
        for j in range(10):
            d = np.random.rand(2) - 0.5
            c = self.toDraw[j].center + d
            self.toDraw[j].center = c
            self.ax.add_patch(self.toDraw[j])
        return []

    def justPlot(self):
        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animationManage,
                                   init_func=self.init,
                                   interval=20,
                                   repeat=True)
        self.fig.show()

justATest = myMovie()
justATest.justPlot()
```

Comment: Hi, i figured it out myself. If one adds the command self.toDraw[j].remove() in the first line of the loop in animationManage it works out fine. Many other approaches using collections and clear axis did not work out. I know it is not supposed to leave the solution in the comment line, but "answer your own question" is not available because of the stack overflow point system. So I hope this approach is feasible to others as well.

Comment: In my more complex "real life problem". It turned out that remove is not working. If I add it in this "real life problem" simply nothing is drawn at all. Animation and Matplotlib seems like riddle wrapped up in an enigma to me. So in fact for some problems "remove" might be a solution but I am still very interessed in any other approch...